# Java Encryption using XTEA

Tags: java, encryption

How would I encrypt a string using the XTEA scheme in Java.

Thanks

```
    public class run {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

            XTEA2 x= new XTEA2("keykey");
            String s = "hi there";
            byte[] theBytes = s.getBytes();


            System.out.println("Plaintext: " + new String(theBytes));

            x.encrypt(theBytes); //theBytes now contains the encrypted data

            System.out.println("Crypo Text: " + new String(theBytes));


            x.decrypt(theBytes); //theBytes now contains the decrypted data

            System.out.println("Decrypted: " + new String(theBytes));
            String str = new String(theBytes); //decrypted String




        }
    }
|
```

Works if it is padded properly.
Thanks guys

Comment: What's with the downvotes? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: -1 For not providing enough information on what do he have already. I assume you've  noting so far. For the given question my answer was correct ( a link to the complete implementation of XTEA used by the H2 Database ) but in turn I've got a downvote.

Comment: How do you know it was from him? I ask, because there are a lot of pedants lurking around that down-vote anyone who mentions the fact that crypto code actually *can* be written outside an ivory tower.

Comment: @ericskon: We've been here for a long while don't we? Let's say I just know. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need this method to convert the String to a byte array:

```
 public static byte[] convertStringToByteArray(String stringToConvert) {
    byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();

    return theByteArray;
}
```

then, use [this code](https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/db4oME/com/db4o/io/crypt/XTEA.java) from the db4o project, and call its methods like:

```
byte[] theBytes = convertStringToByteArray("the string");
encrypt(theBytes); //theBytes now contains the encrypted data
```

for encryption, and

```
decrypt(theBytes); //theBytes now contains the decrypted data
String str = new String(theBytes); //decrypted String
```

Answer (score 2):

After searching on google I found out that you can manually implement a XTEA scheme with using the BlockCipher interface.

[H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) implemented a version with this interface which you can find here: [XTEA.JAVA on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/security/XTEA.java)

The problem here is that you'll need to modify the **encrypt/decrypt(byte[], byte[], int)** methods to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This:

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+encryption+XTEA  gave me this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA  which finally gave me this:

http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/security/XTEA.java

Which I think is what you want

**EDIT**

I don't know if you have read this already but here it goes.

Java [security](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html) API provide the  [architecture](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) needed for cryptography

You get a Cypher using [Cipher.getInstace()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29) method:

*like*

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

But by default java do not provide a cipher for [XTEA](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html)

However you are given the means to register [your own](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) .

I've never had the need to follow the complete process, I guess you have to fulfill a number of interfaces and register your implementation.

In case you need to go that far, you can use the implementation mentioned earlier. It is the one used by H2 DB.

I hope this helps.